# How to setup multi master replication in mysql

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-master

After hours of searching I find lots of tutorials that do only 2 server Master Master. Now I wonder how to setup multi master setup because this is more suitable in my business. Because when the WAN connection is down my transaction in area's are still on going and then when the connection is back the changes in servers will be sync on. That's why i need multi master setup. Thanks in advance for any help and tips

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Server master-master replication is possible for max 2 nodes.

You might want to use Galera Cluster (Percona Xtradb Cluster or Mariadb Galera cluster) Or Oracle's NDB Cluster to achieve HA as a better solution than master-master.

Comment: im new with the galera I never use one. question does it work with mysql 5.0?

Comment: Does it works in windows?

Comment: @dotcom It's not an add-on that you integrate with existing mysql but a separate install. You can get Percona xtradb cluster from https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtradb-cluster. and not it doesnt work on windos.